# Error when using panda module to read csv

Tags: python, file, pandas, module, keyerror

```
companyName = companyList[companyID-1]
data = pd.read_csv("C:\Feedback and Complaints_Sample Dataset.csv",sep=',')  # read file with panda module
desiredOutput = data["Co. Name" == companyName]
desiredOutput.to_csv("1.txt", sep = ",", index=False, header=False)
desiredOutput = data["Co. Name" == companyName]  # For desiredOutput, it'll be when co-name equals companyName
```

I've obtained an error message while using panda module.
Please advise.
Following is the error message:

```
   desiredOutput = data["Co. Name" == companyName]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1797, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1804, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1084, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2851, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1572, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3824)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3704)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 686, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12280)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 694, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12231)
KeyError: False
```

Comment: If you are asking some pandas related question , please add `pandas` tag

Comment: i was denied writing a pandas tag as I do not have 1500 reputation

Comment: scratch that, i could write "pandas" but not panda. my bad.

Comment: Can you try this ? `desiredOutput = data.loc[data["Co. Name"].isin(companyName),:]`

Comment: That gave this error:
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to Series.isin(), you passed a 'str'

Comment: make this line `companyName = companyList[companyID-1]` to a list

Comment: What is the value of `companyName`?

Comment: The value of company name will be a string. Such as "Advisor Incoporation".

However, when I translate it to a list, it'll become
['A','D','V','S','O','R'] instead, which is not actually what I want, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `data` DataFrame with column, which name is `"Co. Name"`, then you can get all rows with your specified condition by using this snippet of code:

```
companyName = companyList[companyID-1]
data = pd.read_csv("C:\Feedback and Complaints_Sample Dataset.csv",sep=',')  # read file with pandas module
desiredOutput = data[data["Co. Name"] == companyName]
```